# Enabling georeferenced TIF file to rectify in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing, geotiff-tiff

I have added a TIF file (size 1,433 KB) in ArcGIS 10.2.2 and defined numerous georeferencing points, with the aim of creating a raster file for conversion to polygons.

However, on clicking the “Rectify” and "Save" buttons, it returns the message “Error – Failed to save raster dataset”. The same occurred when I repeated the procedure with a BMP file.

Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong, or how I might get it to work?

Comment: Do you still see your links when you click the "View Link Table" button ? Just a thought but I would probably try re-starting ArcMap and/or my system and trying again.

Comment: I fear that having restarted just the ArcGIS, all the links have disappeared as well.

Comment: You can save the links and load them back in after you restart. What is the coordinate system of your data frame and your data?

Comment: If you click "Update Georeferencing" from the Georeferencing drop-down in the Georeferencing toolbar, the control points will be saved in a .TIF.AUX.XML file in the same directory as the TIF. Also, are you sure you have write-access to the directory?

Comment: Thanks for your replies - I see the tif.aux.xml files as recently saved; the coordinates system of the underlying layer is GCS_North_American_1983, which I am trying to apply to the map in the TIF. I do have write-access to the directory.

Comment: The problem seems to have originated in my not changing from the default ArcGIS target directory. If I make sure to define the directory myself, then the error message doesn't appear. Thank you all again for helping to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Make sure that your output location is the same as your scanned image. Worked with me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem "Error – Failed to save raster dataset". For me, turns out the issue was that I was saving onto a drive whose free space was less than the amount of space required to store the new georeferenced image. Changing the directory the TIF was saved in resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problems was related with the spatial reference used (WGS84), that was giving me the cell size as 0.0000000

I changed the spatial reference of the data from WGS84 to the UTM zone, and also changed it in the Data Frame Properties and the problem was solved.

(The cell did not appear anymore as 0.0000)

Answer (score 0):

I also had an error pop up ("Error – Failed to save raster dataset") when I attempted to rectify + save the image from the georeferencing toolbar.

For me, the problem was that the "Name" field. The file name I was putting in the "Name" field was too long. ArcGIS is pretty picky about naming, so one of the first things I check when troubleshooting is that the name or directory I'm saving to doesn't have spaces, special characters, or is too long. In this case, the file name I was saving was too long, so I shortened it to 9 characters. I believe the maximum length is 13 characters for the file name for rasters.

More info on naming can be found [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00590000001q000000)