# ArcGIS stops responding during Georeferencing Save?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing

Im using ArcGIS 10.2.  I had an ealier problem that I think I found an answer to [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113893/enabling-georeferenced-tif-file-to-rectify-in-arcgis-for-desktop/141858#141858) while georeferencing an aerial photo. My current issue is that whenever I go to rectify the georeference points, the program stops responding.

I've made sure I'm saving the .tiff file to where the original image is located so no issues there. After having this happen a couple times I realized the program was still saving the georeference points and I could force shut down ArcGIS, open it up, and reference the new .tiff file in.

I think it's strange that the program stops responding (to the point where I have to close it) but still saves the file I was trying to save in the first place? Does this happen to anyone else and/or does it indicate something about my computer or ArcGIS program?

Comment: Is your original tiff/your save location local or on a network drive?  Also, how long of a wait of 'not responding' before you're killing it?  And, do you see any errors/info about previous sessions if you go to Geoprocessing-->Results?

Comment: @MaryBeth the original tiff and save location are on a network drive. I usually give it 5-10 minutes before killing it, once I tried longer (15-20) but still no "waking up". And no, geoprocessing doesn't show any errors or even info about previous sessions in results. Ive been working from the georeferencing toolbar if that means anything!

Comment: I sometimes have issues with ArcMap and our network drive, especially with raster data. I sometimes try saving locally and then copying the rasters over later. Not guaranteeing that it will work for you, but hopefully that gives you a potential workaround.  I have a few people who will kill a job after less than 5 minutes of waiting, so wanted to make sure you were giving it ample time, which it sounds like you are.

Comment: It look like you have ArcGIS 10.2 and you might need to upgrade to 10.2.2 patches to correct the problem ?

Comment: Good to know, I will definitely look into that! @MaryBeth thanks for the tip!